# data is not inserted using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a following main files:

index.php:

```
<?php
include_once("inc/config.php");
$view = $_GET["view"];
include_once "template.php";
?>
```

config.php:

```
define("HOST","localhost");
define("USER","root");
define("PASS","*******");
define("DATABASE","abc");

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS,DATABASE);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

view/create_account.php:

```
<?php 
include_once(CLASS_PATH."create_account.php"); 
$acc = new account();

if((isset($_POST)) and ($_REQUEST['mode']=="insert"))
{
    $acc->insert_orginfo();
}
?>
```

class/create_account.php:

```
<?php
class account
{

    function __construct () {

    }

    /* ----  insert organization info into table  ---- */
    function insert_orginfo()
    {
        extract($_POST);

        $query  = "insert into `organisationinfo` 
                     (`org_name`, `addr1`, `addr2`, `city`, `state`, `country`, `pin`, `tax_number`, `url`) 
                   values 
                   ('$org_name', '$add1', '$add2', '$city', '$state', '$country', '$pincode', '$tax_no', '$url')";

        $mysqli->query($query);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
        return $mysqli->insert_id;
    }
}
?>
```

`index.php` file include `config.php` and `template.php` file and using `template.php`   file i include view file(exa. view/create_account.php). using view file i call the function of class.

now, the problem is data is not inserted.if i add `config.php` file in `class/create_account.php` then it is working.But this class file and view file is finally included in `index.php` and in `index.php` file config file is included.

> means index.php file include template.php file. template.php file include  view/create_account.php file and view/create_account.php file include class/create_account.php

so what is the problem here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are all the variables that you use in the INSERT declared (`$org_name` etc) ? seems like they're out of scope. BTW, your code might be vulnerable to sql-injection.

Comment: this variable is in view file, i have not included in quetion. beacause that is not the problem.

Comment: Change "include_once" to "require_once" to check that the includes are being called (or turn on error reporting).

Comment: no error.page is blank.even if i write static query,the result is same. problem is `$mysqli` is not  set in class file.  if i include `config.php` in class file then  all working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scope question. mysqli is not "in scope" in the insert function.

Fastest solution is to make it "global". http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php - see the section on the "global" keyword.

```
  function insert_orginfo()
  {

    $query  = "insert into `organisationinfo` (`org_name`, `addr1`, `addr2`, `city`, `state`, `country`, `pin`, `tax_number`, `url`) values ('$org_name', '$add1', '$add2', '$city', '$state', '$country', '$pincode', '$tax_no', '$url')";

    global $mysqli;   // bring MySQL into scope.

    $mysqli->query($query);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    return $mysqli->insert_id;
```

Comment: Thanks it is working. but what is  the global solution so i have a no need of write `global $mysqli` in each function?

Comment: For now, run with $global in each function. Many sites/frameworks work that way. The alternative is something called "singletons" (and there's a debate if they are good or bad) or you pass the MySQL object to the class contructor and save as a class variable. Then you can reference $this->  (but there are also downsides to this approach as well)

Answer (score 0):

try this also

```
/* ----  insert organization info into table  ---- */
    function insert_orginfo()
    {
        extract($_POST);
       global $mysqli;
        $query  = "insert into organisationinfo (org_name, addr1, addr2, city, state, country, pin, tax_number, url) values ('$org_name', '$add1', '$add2', '$city', '$state', '$country', '$pincode', '$tax_no', '$url')";

        $mysqli->query($query);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
        return $mysqli->insert_id;
    }
```

Comment: nice catch without back ticks